# Install CA Certifcate using ADB?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, adb, samsung-galaxy-s-4, certificates

I'm in an annoying chicken-and-the-egg loop. Android Browser (the stock browser) is rejecting a bunch of sites certified by Comodo certificate authority. I'm on Comodo's site trying to download their [AddTrust External CA Root](http://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/945/0/root-addtrust-external-ca-root), but I'm not getting the prompts to allow the download. The download never completes.

I want to try a sidestep the Android Browser problems by installing the CA root certificate in the certifcate store over a tether using ADB. Unfortunately, I can't find the ADB commands to do it:

```
$ adb --help 2>&1 | grep -i cert
$
```

How do I use ADB to install the damn certificate?

If I can't use ADB, then what tool does Android provide to install one?

---

The phone is a Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 5.0.1. It is stock and not rooted.

I'm familiar with [Add & remove certificates](http://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2844832?hl=en) from Google Help and [How to install trusted CA certificate on Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4461360/608639). The Stack Overflow question is old, and it predates ICS where the store changed.